# How to add each()

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple slideshow, but I need to be able to have multiple slideshows on a single page. Currently the jQuery is ignoring the additional `.archive_slideshow` slides.

http://jsfiddle.net/LJc7g/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
    $('.slide').hide();
    $('.active').show();
    $('.slide').click(function(){
        $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
        if ( $('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
             $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
        }
        else {
            $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        }
        $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
        $('.slide').hide();
        $('.active').show();
    });
});
```

Whats the best way? Am I on the right track? http://jsfiddle.net/LJc7g/1/

Thank you

Comment: change it to $( ".archive_slideshow" )

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/LJc7g/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working jsfiddle : [jsfiddle.net/LJc7g/7](http://jsfiddle.net/LJc7g/7)

The point is you have asigned $(this) to self, and then used it incorrectly. Do this and it will work fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "div.archive_slideshow" ).each(function() {
        var self = $(this);

        self.find('.slide').first().addClass('active');
        self.find('.slide').hide();
        self.find('.active').show();

        self.find('.slide').click(function(){
            self.find('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
            if ( $('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
                self.find('.slide').first().addClass('active');
            }
            else {
                self.find('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
            }
            self.find('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
            self.find('.slide').hide();
            self.find('.active').show();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Similar to what I had, just putting it here for slightly alternate syntax without using .find -- http://jsfiddle.net/LJc7g/11/

Comment: i am sorry @francisco.preller , but have you answered before, i just cant find it so i hadn't seen what you have done

Comment: I had not answered, nor is there anything to be sorry for. Hope it works out for @uriah!

Comment: Thanks @Francisco, the alternative to .find is great.